# Retrieving an object function tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

```
class App_1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)   
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
           frame = F(container, self)
           self.frames[F] = frame
           frame.grid(row=0, column =0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lf_empresa = ttk.Labelframe(self, text="Empresa")
        self.lf_empresa.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.create_lf_empresa() 

    def create_lf_empresa(self):
        self.t, self.i, self.id = tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), 0             
        self.l_empresa = tk.Label(self.lf_empresa, textvariable = self.t, fg = "blue", font = VARIABLE_FONT)
        self.l_empresa.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky="SW")
        self.next_button = ttk.Button(self.lf_empresa, text="next", command=lambda: self.new_id())
        self.next_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="SW")
        self.id_label = tk.Label(self.lf_empresa, textvariable = self.i , fg = "blue", font = VARIABLE_FONT)
        self.id_label.grid(row=0, column = 2, sticky="SW")

     def new_id(self):
         self.id = self.id + 1
         self.update_variables()

     def update_variables(self):
         database.select_data(self.id)
         self.t.set(database.data["empresa"])   
         self.i.set(str(self.id))


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
            ***


class DataBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sq.connect("test_1.sqlite")
        self.cursor =self.db.cursor()
    def select_data(self, i):
        self.data = {"empresa": ""}
        self.cursor.execute("select  empresa from empresas 
        where id_e = ?", (i, )); empresa = self.cursor.fetchone()

        if empresa != None:
           self.data["id_e"] = empresa[0]
        else:
          **HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GO TO new_id in PageOne**


database = DataBase()       
app = App_1()
app.mainloop()
```

I just want to call the new_id function from the DataBase object at the else part, trying to skip where there is no "id" on the database, so the interface will get the new "id" to look up at the data base, without pushing the button "next".

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the PagOne *class* (spelling error?) as opposed to creating an **instance** of the class from DataBase. Try the following. It demonstrates the PageOne.anyfunction is called.

```
class PageOne(Tk.Frame):
    def anyfunction(self):
        print("In PageOne anyfunction")

class DataBase():
    data = None
    if data == None:
        # Create an INSTANCE of PageOne.
        p = PageOne()
        # Call the anyfunction of the PageOne object.
        p.anyfunction()
```